# Ruby use gets to read lines from a socket request causes blocking

Tags: ruby, socket.io

I'm currently study ruby and making a server with socket support.
Now I need to parse socket request into HTTP METHOD, URI, VERSION, HEADERS and BODY.

I've learned that there should be an empty line between headers and body, i.e.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:8096

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: keep-alive
```

For now I'm trying to read in each line and parse it by

```
@request = server.accept
while line = @request.gets
    ...
    parse_request_line(line)
    ...
    parse_header(line)
    ...
end
```

However, when after read in the last empty line, the while loop will be blocked by gets, because it is waiting for some more input.

I tried modified the code above to

```
@request = server.accept
while line = @request.gets
    break if line.to_s.strip.length == 0
    ...
    parse_request_line(line)
    ...
    parse_header(line)
    ...
end
```

It seems work, when meet an empty line then break the loop.
However, when the request includes a body, the break will interrupt read the rest of the request, body.

i.e
    GET / HTTP/1.1

```
Host: localhost:8096

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: keep-alive
# here is an empty line between headers and body

This is a body .... some contents here
1213123123
```

And then I tried Socket::recv. Seemed the same with gets, will block the program to be continued.
I have no idea now how to solve it.
Any suggestions please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end of an http request is usually defined by the length of the body. This is usually given by either the use of the content-length header or by the use of the chunked transfer encoding (a zero sized chunk ends the request) . For more details see the 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4.

There is no particular reason to believe that the end of the request body will occur and the end of the line, so using gets is not a good idea.

Just using `read` should be enough, but you need to calculate the number of bytes you expect to be present so that you know when you have finished reading the body.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I forgot about content-length... Now I'm using this value to check if does the request has a body and read how much bytes then. Seems working well. Thanks!